# Broken <a> tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Recently I'm working on a website which is contain of galleries. I store the information
of each album in a database and the I fetch them to create links containing field `AlbumId`
with `Eval("AlbumId")`. The code is exactly like below:

```
<a href="/ShowAlbum.aspx?AlbumId=" + <%# Eval("AlbumId") %>><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
```

which finally results in:

```
~/ShowAlbum.aspx?AlbumId=
```

The `AlbumId` is empty.

Does anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Consider the context; the first part is pure text unhandled by ASP.NET, only the <% ... %> is parsed and handled. You're basically saying "give me <a href=... +", then what my eval results in, then ">", then another eval, then "</a>". See what happens if you use runat="server" (which in turns parses that into a server-side html element that can be manipulated) or switching to an <asp:HyperLink ... />

Comment: `<a href='"/ShowAlbum.aspx?AlbumId=" + Eval("AlbumId") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></a>`

Comment: have a look at my answer. hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In href when you complete the double quote (") it means the value of the href has been ended here. 
And after that if you append dynamic value using eval it will give you an error **Invalid Token**

You should put Eval between double quotes as mentioned below :

```
<a href="/ShowAlbum.aspx?AlbumId=<%# Eval("Link") %>"><%# Eval("Episode") %></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try in this way

```
 <a href='<%# "ShowAlbum.aspx?AlbumId="+Eval("Albumid")%>'><% Eval("Title") %></a>
```

Let me know the output.

Comment: Welcome and Mark my answer as correct. So that others will use of it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Eval(), and Bind() not suport for double quotes  (" ") it support single Quotes  for (' ')
so try this

```
<a href="/ShowAlbum.aspx?AlbumId=" + <%# Eval('AlbumId') %>><%# Eval('Title') %></a>
```

Comment: It's not like that. Eval() will support ("") quotes. Rather it won't support for code - nuget expression.